# Stop LinearGradientBrush repeating

Tags: graphics, gdi+, gradient

I'm trying to figure out how to stop LinearGradientBrush to repeat along with shape I'm drawing. So, for example I created gradient with height equal to 50, but next I draw rectangle with height equal to 150. In that case gradient will repeat itself three times. But I'd like to draw only first gradient and draw nothing for the rest of rectangle.
Seems GradientBrush in WPF supports SpreadMethod(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientbrush.spreadmethod.aspx) for this purpose, but does something exists for WinForms as well?

Answer (score 2):

Paul, I think the easiest way may be to create your fill the same way, but only draw using a rect of 50 pixels.  If you need to fill the other 100 pixels with a specific color, then do a solid fill with that color first.

Alternatively, you can try to set a blend in your gradient fill (LinearGradientbrush::SetBlend), but that seems like a lot of effort to achieve the same effect.